# Spawn Terrain at end of current terrain

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im learning Unity and C#. Im making an endless runner skiing game. I have tiles spawning fine I need to spawn a terrain under the tiles that acts as snow and has tress to act as a floor around the tiles. The player goes through a box that triggers another terrain to spawn at the end of the current terrain but I need this to keep spawning at the end of the current terrain to make the terrain look infinite. I have another terrain spawning at the end but after the player has moved through the second one, no more are spawned because I need to get the position of the end of the terrain to add another. Is there anyway to get the position of the end of the terrain to attach to the end? Below is the code with the position to spawn the second terrain. Thanks

```
     private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
        {
            Instantiate(terrain, new Vector3(-477.1f, -1, 959.35f), Quaternion.identity);
            Debug.Log("Box");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The edge is half the distance from the center of the previous.

Imagine a terrain that is 400m, with an origin at 0.
The next terrain is centered at 400, because the first terrain spans from -200 to 200.

To place the each terrain:

1. Track the terrain number (zero based)
2. Multiply by terrain size
3. Add the origin offset

Example

```
terrain pos = size * number + origin

terrain (0) = 400 * 0 + 0
terrain (1) = 400 * 1 + 0
terrain (2) = 400 * 2 + 0
```